# having trouble with responsive css design

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}

.about-title {
    background-color: #fc0321;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
    .about {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <h3 class="about-title">Welcome to Mahasakthi Harvester Spares</h3>
  <p style="font-weight: 200;">MAHASAKTHI HARVESTER SPARES, established in the year 2017 by high end professionals in the field of Combine Harvester Manufacturing and Repairing. We are leading wholesaler, retailer and manufacturer of combine harvester spares dealing in Standard,Balkar,Kartar,Preet and Claas Combine Harvesters.Our Product ranges from Machined spares, Fabricated spares, sheet metal spares, Rubber spares,Shafts,Bearings,Belts, Oils ,Grease,Filters,Rubber Tracks,Rollers,Sprockets to all miniature spares.</p>
  <a href="#" class="about-button">Read More...</a>
</div>
```

In the above code I tried for the responsive design but i'm not getting it.
I mentioned width as 87% for the desktop screens and then I changed the width to 100% for the smaller screens.But the width is not changing.I'm  having trouble with this.

Comment: *I mentioned width as 87% for the desktop screens* --> where? there is nothing in the code

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .about-title {
      background-color: #fc0321;
      color: #ffffff;
      padding: 5px;
      font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 100px;
    }
      //--------------
    .about {
       width: 87%
       }
     //--------------
    @media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
      .about {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

You didn't write the default width value in your code

Comment: I mentioned the default width in the code. but it didn't work.I forgot to mention here in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example that @AFF did in a snippet. As you can see it is working. If you are still having issues, then there is likely some conflicting CSS that is overriding your CSS. Please try and reproduce the issue you are having in a snippet using the `width:85%` for desktop widths, so we can help with your specific issue.

If seeing this working example helps solve your issue, then please accept @AFF answer.

```css
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   box-sizing:border-box;
}

.about-title {
    background-color: #fc0321;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.about {
 width:85%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
    .about {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <h3 class="about-title">Welcome to Mahasakthi Harvester Spares</h3>
  <p style="font-weight: 200;">MAHASAKTHI HARVESTER SPARES, established in the year 2017 by high end professionals in the field of Combine Harvester Manufacturing and Repairing. We are leading wholesaler, retailer and manufacturer of combine harvester spares dealing in Standard,Balkar,Kartar,Preet and Claas Combine Harvesters.Our Product ranges from Machined spares, Fabricated spares, sheet metal spares, Rubber spares,Shafts,Bearings,Belts, Oils ,Grease,Filters,Rubber Tracks,Rollers,Sprockets to all miniature spares.</p>
  <a href="#" class="about-button">Read More...</a>
</div>
```